# Error running script python

Tags: python, pandas

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flemos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import hashtable, tslib, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\flemos\Desktop\OptimalRoadTripHtmlSaveAndDisplay.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\flemos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\pandas\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    "extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace' to build the C extensions first.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the same version of python as your library i.e. both 64bit or both 32bit.

Comment: I'm using pythton 3.5 with panda 0.16.2

Comment: Are they 64bit or 32 bit though?

Run this to determine the python architecture  
  
`import platform`
`platform.architecture()`

And then install the same version of the panda library.